# A friend gave me his source code and I'm having trouble fixing an error in FNVHash

Tags: c++

```
constexpr unsigned int FNVHash(const void* const data, const int len)
{
    unsigned char* p = const_cast<unsigned char*>(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data));
    unsigned int h = 2166136261;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        h = (h * 16777619) ^ p[i];

    return h;
}
```

the issue I'm having is in the compiler:

```
Error   C3615   constexpr function 'UTILS::FNVHash' cannot result in a constant expression (compiling source file **the source file** ) **the file path/project name**
```

i dont know a lot of cpp so this could totally be a beginners question. If it is, I'm sorry to have wasted your time. I tried to google search, but google doesn't know what any of this means either.

Edit: I should say that going to him for help is not an option

Comment: From clang: `note: reinterpret_cast is not allowed in a constant expression`

Comment: @StephenNewell how would i get around this/fix it?

Comment: Change the type of `data` to a `unsigned char const*`, then delete all the casts.

Comment: @StephenNewell what do you mean delete all the casts? Would that just leave me with data?

Comment: oh wait i see what you mean now, thanks

Comment: never mind @StephenNewell im lost again

Comment: Just remove the `constexpr`. Constant expressions cannot have pointer casts in them.

Comment: Change the type of `data` to `uint8_t`.  The `char` type is defined by range, not by bit width.  Also, pass the data as a vector:  `FNVHash(const std::vector<uint8_t> data)`.  You don't need a size parameter because the vector can be queried about its length.